# Angular datatable custom button enable

Tags: angular, datatable

I have a datatable with a custom button, using Angular, not jquery, how can i get a handle on my custom button to enable it later?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
            this.dtOptions = {
                ...
                buttons: [
                   {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        text: 'Save as Excel'
                   },
                   {
                        text: 'Custom',
                        enable: false,
                        // later i want to enable this button on a particular event
                        ...
                   }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i ended up solving my problem, just by using the browser's developer's console to brute force how to access the button and change enable/disable of it...

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    // this was already in my component so i used it as my starting point
    // in my callback below
    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective) datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dtOptions = {
            ...
            buttons: [
               {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Save as Excel'
               },
               {
                    text: 'Custom',
                    enable: false,
                    // later i want to enable this button on a particular event
                    ...
                    className: 'my-button',
                    attr: {
                        id: 'myButton',
                        title: 'this button does stuff'
                    }
               }
            ]
        }
    }

    someCallback(e) {
        ...
        if (someCondition) {
            datatableElement['dt'].button('.my-button').enable();
            // i tried this but during typescript compile it
            // complained that dt is private...
            // datatableElement.dt.button('.my-button').enable();
        } else {
            datatableElement['dt'].button('.my-button').disable();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```